# Expand/Collapse Table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a table which expand or collapse. My requirement is when I click on table row then hidden row show or when I click on other table row then previous open row hide or show relative hide row. I found a jquery jxpand perfect for me it show hidden row but when I click on other row previous hidden data remain open not hide I want previous hide or show new related row hidden data. My code snippet is as follow

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();
            
            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
            //$("#report").jExpand();
        });
```

```css
#report { border-collapse:collapse;}
        #report h4 { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
        #report img { float:right;}
        #report ul { margin:10px 0 10px 40px; padding:0px;}
        #report th { background:#7CB8E2 url(header_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; color:#fff; padding:7px 15px; text-align:left;}
        #report td { background:#C7DDEE none repeat-x scroll center left; color:#000; padding:7px 15px; }
        #report tr.odd td { background:#52edc7; cursor:pointer; }
        #report div.arrow { background:transparent url(arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -16px; width:16px; height:16px; display:block;}
        #report div.up { background-position:0px 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table id="report">
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Official languages</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>United States of America</td>
            <td>306,939,000</td>
            <td>9,826,630 km2</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>show/hide</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img src="125px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" alt="Flag of USA" />
                <h4>Additional information</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usa">USA on Wikipedia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://nationalatlas.gov/">National Atlas of the United States</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.nationalcenter.org/HistoricalDocuments.html">Historical Documents</a></li>
                 </ul>   
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>United Kingdom </td>
            <td>61,612,300</td>
            <td>244,820 km2</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>show/hide</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img src="125px-Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg.png" alt="Flag of UK" />
                <h4>Additional information</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_kingdom">UK on Wikipedia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.visitbritain.com/">Official tourist guide to Britain</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.statistics.gov.uk/StatBase/Product.asp?vlnk=5703">Official 
                        Yearbook of the United Kingdom</a></li>
                </ul>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>1,147,995,904</td>
            <td>3,287,240‡ km2</td>
            <td>Hindi, English</td>
            <td>show/hide</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img src="125px-Flag_of_India.svg.png" alt="Flag of India" />
                <h4>Additional information</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India">India on Wikipedia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://india.gov.in/">Government of India</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://wikitravel.org/en/India">India travel guide</a></li>
                 </ul>   
            
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>33,718,000</td>
            <td>9,984,670 km2</td>
            <td>English, French</td>
            <td>show/hide</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img src="125px-Flag_of_Canada.svg.png" alt="Flag of Canada" />
                <h4>Additional information</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada">Canada on Wikipedia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://atlas.gc.ca/site/index.html" >Official 
                        Government of Canada online Atlas of Canada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://wikitravel.org/en/Canada">Canada travel guide</a></li>
                 </ul>   
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>82,060,000</td>
            <td>357,021 km2</td>
            <td>German</td>
            <td>show/hide</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img src="125px-Flag_of_Germany.svg.png" alt="Flag of Germany" />
                <h4>Additional information</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany">Germany on Wikipedia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.deutschland.de/home.php?lang=2">Deutschland.de Official Germany portal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.cometogermany.com/">Germany Travel Info</a></li>
                 </ul>   
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <em>* Information taken from Wikipedia</em>
```

like if view UK hidden data then open Canada hidden data UK opened data will again hide and Canada data will open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `$("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();` in the click function.

```
$("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
$("#report tr:first-child").show();

$("#report tr.odd").click(function () {
    $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/Lbhawcnb/)

**Edit**
Based on comments - we can hide the current selected element something like the following:

```
$("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
$("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
$("#report tr:first-child").show();

$("#report tr.odd").click(function () {
    var trToToggle = $(this).next("tr");
    $("#report tr:not(.odd)").not(trToToggle).hide();
    $(trToToggle).toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

Edited jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/Lbhawcnb/1/)

Comment: good work, but it always show one open row i want show or hide both, like if i open last row or if i want to again hide it but it is remain open not hide

Comment: you mean to say if the same row is clicked twice then hide the current row.  Right?

Comment: See edited answer or see the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/Lbhawcnb/1/)

Comment: great job, thanks for your fast help. thanks broo proud on you.

Comment: sorry bro for again disturbing, when i click on any row <th> row is also hiding  you can also see in your fiddle